# Passing a pointer to WebAssembly from JavaScript which is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, c, memory-management, webassembly, emscripten

Below given is my JavaScript code.

```
  a = "hello"

  a_ascii = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++)
    a_ascii.push(a[i].charCodeAt(0));

  a_typedArray = new Float32Array(a_ascii.length)
  for (let i=0; i<a_ascii.length; i++) {
    a_typedArray[i] = a_ascii[i]
  }
  a_buffer = Module._malloc(a_typedArray.length * a_typedArray.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT)

  Module.HEAPF32.set(a_typedArray, a_buffer >> 2)

  var result = Module.ccall(
      "myFunction", // name of C function
      null, // return type
      [Number, Number], // argument types
      [a_buffer, a.length] // arguments
  );
```

And below given is the C code:

```
extern "C"
{
    void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE myFunction(int *a, int s)
    {
        printf("MyFunction Called\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n%d\n", s);
    }

}
```

The output of C code is given below:

```
1120927744 1120534528 1121452032 1121452032 1121845248

5
```

though it should have been:

```
104 101 108 108 111

5
```

Please, let me know what's wrong with the code.

I took reference from: [link](https://blog.usejournal.com/string-manipulation-webassembly-5011e64c6b76)

Comment: Why do you need a float on int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Float32Array` in JavaScript while `int*` in C.

You should do either one of:

- Change `Float32Array` to `Int32Array` in your JavaScript code
- Change `int*` to `float*` and `"%d "` to `"%.0f "` in your C code

Comment: Hey MikeCAT i just asked this in comments

Comment: Changing Float32Array to Int32Array in JavaScript code didn't work.